# trying to make a budget calculator but I'm lost

Tags: python

I have an assignment with the following request:

The program asks the student the max budget they have for the month. Then the program asks the student for the expenses he/she had on the first day of the month (On the screen it would say: What were your expenses on day #1?) And so on and so forth it keeps asking for the expenses of each of the following days. The program stops when one of two conditions occurs: when the accumulated expenses of the days that have been entered exceed the budget limit, in that case the program displays a message indicating that the budget has been met; or, in the second case, when the 30th day is reached and the corresponding expense has been entered, in that case if there is money left over from the budget the program must tell you how much is left over.

I'm trying to figure if using if function some cycles and an input option to save the money spent in a day in that variable and also assign the max budget to recall a stop when the code finds I'm over budget in one of the 30 inputs and show which day I went over budget

this is what I currently have I want to know what I'm doing wrong and in what I can improvise

```
Max = 240

print(
    "Lets keep on track your expenses :)" + "\n"
)

Spent = int(input("input todays expenses:"))

if(Spent < Max):
    int(input("type the money you will spend the next days"))
elif(Spent> Max):
    print("you went overbudget you can't spend more, sorry! :(")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show a sample input, the expected output, and the actual output (or what happened).

Comment: example imput, knowing is an integer we will input a number like 32 and it will ask me for the next day like accumulating, until wether i arrive till day 30 or 30th input or untill i get over the value saved on the max variable that's the max spending budget

Comment: example, day 1 32, day 2 25 for a total of 57, and up until the expences hit the max i states as the max expences i can do, once i hit that number it will show you went over budget

Comment: That's a **description** of what you are **trying to do**. I'm asking you to also say what **happened**. What happened when you enter "32"? If instead you enter "16", what happened? You came here to ask a question because your code isn't doing what you want. So, what did the code **actually** do, in these two situations?

Comment: an if cycle making a loop so the program can check if im overbudget yet after every input i give to it ending on a syntax error

Comment: What exactly was the **syntax error**?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Which line causes that syntax error? (If you can't figure out, then delete lines until it stops giving the error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. You can try this:

```
max = 240
day = 1

while True:
    daySpent = input("What were your expenses on day #{} : ".format(day))
    
    max -= int(daySpent)
    
    day += 1
    
    if max <= 0:
        print("exceed the budget limit")
        break
    elif day > 30:
        print("Leftover: ", max)
        break
```

You can simply achieve it using a `while` loop to iterate each day and using `if` condition to break out the loop when conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this  for the days and the total spending, keeping a subtotal as you go along.

```
max = 240
spent = 0
tot_spent = 0
day = 0 
while day < 31:
    if spent < max:
        spent = float(input("input today's expenses: "))
        tot_spent = tot_spent + spent
        day = day + 1
        print('Day ',day, 'Total spent ', tot_spent)
    
    if tot_spent >= max:
        print('You met or exceeded your budget, quit spending!')
        break
    if day == 30 and tot_spent< max:
        print('You are at or near the end of your budget period and the unspent amount = ', max - tot_spent)
    if day == 31:
        break
```